# The battery is 34% charged(or is 34% ), the battery decreased by 4%

Tags: word-usage, american-english

If the battery percentage indicator shows "34%", what will a natural way to express this idea?

> My phone's **battery is 34%**..
>
> My phone's **battery is 34% charged**.

Should "charge" be added in the end? Is there a more natural way to express this idea?

And after a while the phone's battery drains a bit. So what sounds natural:

> My phone's **battery decreased** by 4%.
>
> My phone's **battery drained** by 4%.

Is there a shorter and better way to express this idea?

And what about the battery increasing when put on charger?

> My phone's **battery increased** by 4%.

Is there a more natural way to express it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people would say

> My phone has gone down by 4%
>   My phone has gone up by 4%"

because for most people the battery is implicit in the statement. For this reason we would also say

> My phone is on 34%

although "my phone is 34% charged" is correct it is not what a native would say and sounds unnatural to me as an Englishman.

Comment: I don't think most people would use **on**; they would use **at**.

Answer (score -1):

"*Battery*" is actually a **device**, a thing.

It can not be 34%, increased or decreased.
Same reason mobile companies use examples like "Battery life" or "Battery capacity" etc.
So words like **charged** and **drained** are correct.

Also to use increased/decreased, you can rather say,

> My phone's battery's charging increased/decreased by 4%